# Sequelize Associations not being created

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am designing a system that has People and Users (all Users are people, but not all People are Users). Each of those entities can have multiple Emails. The Sequelize models are set up like this:

### Models

#### Person

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
var Person = sequelize.define('person', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    middleName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    dob: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE
    }
});

return Person;
};
```

#### Company

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

var Company = sequelize.define('company', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    status: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE'),
        defaultValue: 'ACTIVE'
    }
});

return Company;
};
```

#### User

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, Sequelize) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    salt: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(128),
        allowNull: true
    }
});

return User;
};
```

#### Email

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
var Email = sequelize.define('email', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    address: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    status: {
        type: Sequelize.ENUM('ACTIVE','INACTIVE'),
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: 'ACTIVE'
    }
});

return Email;
};
```

### Relations

```
module.exports = function(models) {
    models.Company.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'companiesUsers'});

    models.Email.belongsToMany(models.Person, {through: 'peopleEmails'});
    models.Email.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'usersEmails'});

    models.Person.belongsToMany(models.Email, {through: 'peopleEmails'});

    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Company, {through: 'companiesUsers'});
    models.User.belongsToMany(models.Email, {through: 'usersEmails'});
};
```

### Service

```
module.exports = function (models, uuid, q, sequelize) {
var crypto = require('crypto');

function register(attrs) {
    var salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64').substr(0, 128),
        hash = crypto.createHash('sha1'),
        hashedPassword,
        user,
        company,
        person,
        deferred = q.defer(),
        result = {};

    hash.update(attrs.password + salt, 'utf8');

    hashedPassword = hash.digest('base64');

    sequelize.transaction(function(t) {
        return models.User.create({
            id: uuid.v4(),
            username: attrs.username,
            password: hashedPassword,
            salt: salt
        }).then(function(createdUser) {
            user = createdUser;
            result.user = user.dataValues;
            return models.Company.create({
                id: uuid.v4(),
                name: attrs.companyName,
                description: attrs.companyDescription || null,
                status: 'ACTIVE'
            });
        }).then(function(createdCompany) {
            company = createdCompany;
            result.company = createdCompany.dataValues;
            company.addUser(user);
            return models.Person.create({
                id: uuid.v4(),
                firstName: attrs.firstName,
                lastName: attrs.lastName,
                middleName: attrs.middleName || null,
                userId: user.id
            });
        }).then(function(createdPerson) {
            person = createdPerson;
            result.person = createdPerson.dataValues;
            return models.Email.create({
                id: uuid.v4(),
                address: attrs.emailAddress,
                status: 'ACTIVE'
            });
        }).then(function(email) {
            email.addPerson(person);
        });
    }).then(function() {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

return {
    register: register
}
};
```

### Result

The service executes with no errors, and the `companiesUsers` join entity is created just fine, but `email.addPerson()` nor `person.addEmail()` will create the `peopleEmails` join entity.

I'm not really sure what I can do differently, but I really like Sequelize and would hate to have redo my ORM with another library because I've put a LOT of time into it!

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but perhaps you need a `return` before `email.addPerson(person)`? Otherwise the promise may "finish" before this step completes, and you'd miss the email-person association.

Comment: I will try that and let you know! Thanks.

Comment: That absolutely worked! Thanks for the good eye, friend!

Comment: Can you add that as an answer, and I'll accept?

Comment: Will do. Also, there seems to be another one missing in the `company.addUser()` bit. But this seems to be working...?

Comment: Yes, but there's a return statement after that (to create another model) so it seems to be included in the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this helps, but perhaps you need a return before email.addPerson(person)? Otherwise the promise may "finish" before this step completes, and you'd miss the email-person association.

```
then(function(email) {
   return email.addPerson(person);
   ^^^^^^ this was missing
});
```